# Automated Testing For Heavy UI Apps

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface, testing

How do people test heavy UI applications? Specifically, the UI is in a web browser in an SVG or Canvas element.

Like, say most of the application is drag/drop and resizable and different things that happen as a result of dragging to a certain place or resizing to a certain size.

What are some strategies people use today?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing UI application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616148/unit-testing-ui-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two resources:

Selenium  (http://seleniumhq.org) is a free tool for testing Web applications.

PushToTest (http://pushtotest.com) offers a free small-volume application, a paid high-end application and paid services.